# How to destroy kendo-grid programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, kendo-grid, angular6

I'm trying to destroy the `kendo-grid` each time my component is destroy.

I found out [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/destroy) a way to do it but requires jquery that I don't use:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.destroy();
</script>
```

Any one knows how to do it in angular 6 and typescript?

Thank you

Comment: I believe in kendo's Angular component has implemented a `ngOnDestroy` callback and destroys itself automatically. I do not think you'd need such features. Using ng-if for example would in fact destroy all references if your plan is to toggle or hide grids.

Comment: @JonathanHamel In theory yes, the angular should destroy the kendogrid but I'm facing some performance issues. I have a component that uses the grid. What I want is to make sure that the grid is destroy on the ngOnDestroy and see if that solves my performance issues .